# Unpivot Excell matrix into list, Columns have lables in two rows

Tags: excel, list, unpivot

Good morning
I am trying to turn a excel data matrix into a simple list. I have tried the Power Query in Excel that seemed promising, but my problem is that columns have label groupes into two rows

This is what I have now:

[image: what i have]

this is what I would like to have

[image: what i want]

Many thanks, I hope it is clear.

Comment: could you elaborat on what you have tried with powerquery? which functions? why didn't it work?

Comment: I have tried the Transform/Unpivot command, but does not dea with two rows label in the columns.

Comment: I have since, however, found this that may offer a solution, https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/06/19/unpivot-by-number-of-columns-and-rows-in-powerbi-and-powerquery-in-excel/, but it seems to be a bit slow...